# M_ROW$$ equivalent in PostgreSQL 10

Tags: oracle, postgresql, postgresql-10

How can I define a `M_ROW$$` column equivalent in PostgreSQL 10?

I have a index from Oracle like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "MySchema"."I_SNAP$_MyIndex" ON "MySchema"."MyTable" ("M_ROW$$")
```

I want to migrate it to PostgreSQL.

Comment: What does `M_ROW$$` do?

Comment: `M_ROW$$` is a hidden column type in Oracle

Comment: What does that hidden type do? What is this index doing?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:54170954807993 You can see here for meaning of M_ROW$$. It is added by Oracle internal as I known

Comment: Sorry but I don't see a definition of `M_ROW$$` in that link, perhaps you could explain in your question what `M_ROW$$` is and why you want to index it.

Comment: "*It is recommended that this column be dropped or marked as unused after the redefinition is complete.*" Sounds like some transient thing that doesn't need to be ported.

Comment: You need to explain what this `M_ROW$$` column contains. But it would be much better if you explained the real, underlying problem that you are trying to solve with that index. Maybe there is an equivalent in Postgres, maybe you need to solve with in a completely different way. Not everybody who knows Postgres knows what some hidden Oracle columns are doing.

Comment: If you can't explain what this does, and why you need it, then consider that maybe you don't need this index at all.